# How to add key, value to Json data from mongoDB?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, amazon-s3, mongoose

I stored product data in MongoDB and image in S3. So I'm trying to add img url to each of product data and send it together, but it doesn't work. I'm using node.js. Thanks

```
app.get("/products/getAllProducts", (req, res) => {
      const path=[];
        mongoose.model('Product').find().exec((err, productInfo) => {
          if (err) return res.status(400).send(err);
          productInfo.forEach(productInfo => {
            s3.getSignedUrl(
              "getObject",
              {
                Bucket: Bucket_NAME,
                Key: productInfo.No+'.png'
              },
              (err, url) => {
                if (err) {
                  throw err;
                }
                //console.log(url);
                //path.push(url);
                //path[productInfo.No] = url
                productInfo.img = url;
                //return productInfo;
              }
            );
          })
          res.status(200).json({ success: true, productInfo });
        });
      });
```

Comment: Please expand on what "doesn't work" means

Comment: url wasn't added to productInfo.